# Make variable out of text past a certain point in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="text">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
```

How can I make a variable out of everything past "dolor" in the sentence above with jQuery?

**Edit**

I want the variable's value to be "sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = $('#text').text().match(/dolor/i);
```

Comment: `text` ist actually filled with `dolor`, which is not the required outcome as far as I understood ..

Answer (score 1):

```
function findPartOfString(el, text) {
    var t = $(el).text();
    console.log(t.substr(t.indexOf(text) + (text).length));
}

findPartOfString('div', 'dolor');
```

Answer (score 0):

with javascript:

```
var text = $("#text").text();
text = text.substr(text.indexOf('dolor') + 5);
alert(text);
```